# Django Bootstrap form field won't resize

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to display my django forms but am having trouble getting them to resize.  One of the forms is a text input area and I want it to span most of my panel width.  I've tried multiple things but haven't been able to resize it/make the input area bigger.

**The html**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="text-center">
      Raw sQL Query
    </h4>
  </div>
  <form action="/InterfaceApp/table_search/" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel-body text-center">
      {% bootstrap_form rawsQL %}
      </br> 
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" value="Submit" name="rawsQL">
          {% bootstrap_icon "fire" %} Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**The form**:

```
class TextFieldForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    section_label = kwargs.pop('section_label')
    initial_value = kwargs.pop('initial_value')
    required_val = kwargs.pop('required')

    super(TextFieldForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['text'].label=mark_safe(section_label)
    self.fields['text'].initial=initial_value
    self.fields['text'].required=required_val

  text = forms.CharField()
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me with making the input area wider??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that when you pass in forms to django templates like `{% bootstrap_form formname %}` you have to go into where you defined the form to edit how it looks.  I fixed my resizing issue by doing:

**Form**:

```
class TextFieldForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    section_label = kwargs.pop('section_label')
    initial_value = kwargs.pop('initial_value')
    required_val = kwargs.pop('required')

    super(TextFieldForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['text'].label=mark_safe(section_label)
    self.fields['text'].initial=initial_value
    self.fields['text'].required=required_val

  text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"form-control text-center",'placeholder':".col-md-8"}))
```

**html**:

```
<div class="col-md-8 centering">
   {% bootstrap_form rawsQL %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and [form control sizing](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes).

Comment: I've tried using that method but it doesn't seem to have an effect on my form.  I'm assuming that's because the form is passed in using bootstrap as `{% bootstrap_form rawsQL %}` instead of defined in the html.